# Sum of $s_n=10-8+6.4-5.12+...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I'm asked to find the sum for $s_n=10-8+6.4-5.12+...$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. I discovered that the sum can be written as $$10\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\left(\frac{8}{10}\right)^{n-1}$$

I know from the ratio/roots test the series indeed converges.
My problem is figuring out what it converges to. I don't see how I can use the geometric formula $\frac{a}{1-r}$.

Comment: Hint - The sum can be written as $10\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-8}{10})^{n-1}$

Comment: Isn't $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}10(-1)^{n-1}(\frac{8}{10})^{n-1}=10\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-8}{10})^{n-1}=10\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-8}{10})^{k}$.

Comment: $r$ doesn't have to be positive...

Comment: I thought the series will only converge when $-1<r<1$, then diverge in every other case. Oops

Comment: You have that $r = -8/10$, so it is satisfied that $-1 < r < 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}10(-1)^{n-1}\biggr(\frac{8}{10}\biggr)^{n-1}
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}10\left(\frac{-8}{10}\right)^{n}=10\frac{1}{1+\frac{8}{10}}=\frac{100}{19}
$$

Comment: $100/18$, surely?

Comment: Could you add a justification why that algebraic step works? It certainly looks right after the lower boundary was adjusted but I'm having a hard time proving it

Comment: Never mind I got it now

Comment: @Brian... Toi early in thé morning for this computation -:)